# ASP.NET question regarding getting the IP address of a user

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.servervariables, remote-host

I am trying to fetch the IP address using this:-

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ClientIP;
        ClientIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        Label1.Text = ClientIP;
    }
```

This code outputs 127.0.0.1.

And the code below displays nothing!

```
    string ClientIP;
    ClientIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    Label1.Text = ClientIP;
```

How do I fetch the IP address? The REAL IP address of a user?

[EDIT]

I don't want EXACT location BTW. I need to know the country and then redirect the user to a webpage accordingly.

Comment: Keep in mind that NAT, proxies and so forth will obscure the results.

Comment: yep I know..just need to know the country

Comment: I've had a proxy in the hosting centre that prevented getting the user-IP, so then you won't even get country data.

Comment: If you want to display a page in the "correct language", then *country* is not enough - there are multilingual countries (or foreigners living there). Checking UserLanguages is then better.

Comment: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is the server variable to know about browser's preferred language..right ? I am confused now..preferred language can be set as whatever in browser..isn't it ? So how can we be sure about the country ? Won't fetching IP address be the correct way to know about the country of a visitor??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Request.Params["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Comment: this too is displaying 127.0.0.1 as output

Comment: @happysoul perhaps because you are testing on localhost ?

Answer (score 2):

Using System.Net, try this -

```
// Then using host name, get the IP address list..
          IPHostEntry ipEntry = DNS.GetHostByName (strHostName);
          IPAddress [] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

          for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
          {
              Console.WriteLine ("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString ());
          }
```